# Is there a way to disable fetching the entire value set for a column in Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee

In our "Process" table there is a "Type" column. This column's valueset is defined in an enum in our code. However there are obsolete rows in this table. Meaning that there are rows where "type" is a value that is not present in the code's enum. The problem is whenever we acces ANY (not the obsolete ones) of the rows in this table we get an error that there is an unkown value for that column. Is there a way to disable this feature in hibernate as we do not want to delete these rows.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, of = {})
@Table(name = ProcessEntity.TABLE_NAME)
public class ProcessEntity extends BaseEntity implements ValidityHolder {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "PROCESS";

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "consent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ConsentAnswerEntity> consentAnswers;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "consent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProcessConsentEntity> processConsents;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "consent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ProcessTypeConsentEntity> processTypeConsents;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
private Type TpyeId;
```

Comment: How is the column annotated and how exactly is the column set up in the table?

Comment: @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
    private Type type;

This is how it is declared in our "Process" table

Comment: That is only the entity, not the actual table

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Still missing the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these "obsolete" records no longer fit into your Hibernate data model, then I recommend just moving them to some archive table.  After all, you can't really select them now anyway using Hibernate, so at least at the application level, they serve no purpose.

For a more general way to logically delete a record without physically removing it, look into soft deletion.  Using soft deletion, you would add a single boolean column to the table which, if marked, would indicate that the record is logically no longer there.